# Customize and sysprep modern.ie virtual machines say for VirtualBox?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtualization, snapshot, sysprep

Has anyone done this or know if possible and the steps? MS has VMs for testing IE on modern.ie site. They're clean base images one extract and imports into VM software of choice like VirtualBox to then run. And it is suggested to take a snapshot right after the import to be able to rollback to default state when the Windows trial expires.

I recall VMs still have the same restrictions of physical machines of having machine specific identifiers, so you generally can't directly import a virtual machine from one machine to another w/o minor tweaks.

Wondering about importing the modern.ie VMs, customizing them with additional software & configs, then do sysprep or something againt the image to generalize it again so that anyone can then import a copy of the image w/ no conflicts.

I guess snapshots can't be shared so easily? So might just have each user create their own snapshot after import of custom generalized image.

There any tutorials for this (especially specific to VirtualBox and/or modern.ie VMs)?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that yes, you should Sysprep the environments before creating multiple copies that will be used in the same environment.

There are two ways I would proceed. The first is to configure a base VM, create a snapshot, and Sysprep it, then create a clone of that VM. The original VM would never be boot, just cloned whenever you wanted a new generalized machine. You could also restore the snapshot and reconfigure, then re-Sysprep, if needed.

The second way is to create a virtual deployment server. This virtual machine would have a Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT) deployment share. You would capture an image to this deployment server from your base VM, import any desired apps, then deploy down to the new VMs. One of the big advantages to this route is that you could customize the new environments at the time of deployment. Want a VM with Office and an older version of Flash for testing purposes? Select those options during deployment. Want a VM that is completely up to date with only Java installed? Once you import the desired apps, you can pick and choose from the Windows Deployment Wizard and quickly spin up a new environment with the desired configuration.

https://technet.microsoft.com/windows/dn475741

Comment: For cloning, do you mean just making a copy of the file and boot from the copy rather than the original?

Comment: Sort of, you could create a copy of the VHD file for each new machine. I believe VirtualBox also has a built in clone option (right click the machine).